# How to plot activities by hour based on dataset in ggplot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-ggplot

I'm trying to create code that will plot the number of entries into the MTA by hour. I have a csv dataset of entries and the hours they occur. I've reduced the dataset to a Pandas dataframe with just the entries, and I've added a column for "Hour" to show the time that the entries occur.

However, when plotting, I keep getting a "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." and I'm unclear what this means, or why it's happening.

I've tried adjusting the "Hour" column to a datetime; I've tried using the index instead of the "Hour" column in the dataframe.

```py
from ggplot import *
import pandas as pd

turnstile_weather = pd.read_csv('/home/pi/Documents/Data analysis/turnstile_data_master_with_weather.csv')

def plot_weather_data(turnstile_weather):
    entries_by_hour = pd.DataFrame(turnstile_weather['ENTRIESn_hourly'] \
        .groupby(turnstile_weather['Hour']).sum())
    entries_by_hour['Hour'] = set(turnstile_weather['Hour'])
    plot = ggplot(entries_by_hour, \
        aes(entries_by_hour['Hour'], entries_by_hour['ENTRIESn_hourly'])) \
        + geom_line()
    print(plot)

plot_weather_data(turnstile_weather)
```

I expect to get a line chart, with Hours as the X-axis and Entries by Hour as the Y-axis, but I get an error instead:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3cf39740bb64> in <module>
     10     print(plot)
     11 
---> 12 plot_weather_data(turnstile_weather)

<ipython-input-9-3cf39740bb64> in plot_weather_data(turnstile_weather)
      7     entries_by_hour = pd.DataFrame(turnstile_weather['ENTRIESn_hourly'].groupby(turnstile_weather['Hour']).sum())
      8     entries_by_hour['Hour'] = set(turnstile_weather['Hour'])
----> 9     plot = ggplot(entries_by_hour, aes(entries_by_hour['Hour'], entries_by_hour['ENTRIESn_hourly'])) + geom_line()
     10     print(plot)
     11 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ggplot/ggplot.py in __init__(self, aesthetics, data)
     53         self._aes = aesthetics
     54         self.data = data.copy()
---> 55         self._handle_index()
     56         self.data = self._aes._evaluate_expressions(self.data)
     57         self.data = self._aes.handle_identity_values(self.data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ggplot/ggplot.py in _handle_index(self)
    132 
    133     def _handle_index(self):
--> 134         if '__index__' in self._aes.values():
    135             self.data['__index__'] = self.data.index
    136 

/usr/lib/python3.5/_collections_abc.py in __contains__(self, value)
    688     def __contains__(self, value):
    689         for key in self._mapping:
--> 690             if value == self._mapping[key]:
    691                 return True
    692         return False

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1476         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1477                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1478                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1479 
   1480     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I'm no pro at ggplot, but I think your syntax may be incorrect.  It isn't clear in ggplot if you can say `plot = ggplot(...)`.  I think you just need to invoke `ggplot(...)`.  Try using the internal plotting functions in pandas (which are matplotlib).  It should be a 1-liner to make a scatter plot with that and compare

Comment: Yeah, it works great with matplotlib, but am trying to figure out why ggplot doesn't like the same data. Thanks!